# Collections Debug Visualizer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

While debugging a WP7 app, how do I view a value of a generic dictionary collection?

Answer (score 1):

Press **F9** on the line where you access the dictionary, and then hover it with a mouse after your app stops on the breakpoint.

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) you can find some pics.

Hope I understood your question.

Comment: In particular, check the `entries` field when hovering the dictionary. All keys and their values will be in that collection.